# How to set my own value in session?

Tags: magento-1, session

I need to save value into session. I try to do it in `index.php.` But I can set

```
$inputMessage = 'Hello World';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMySessionvar($inputMessage);
```

only after `Mage::run`. Otherwise it returns error. It is unacceptable because I want to change content depending MySessionvar value.
What can you advise?

Comment: Non-good solution is add this code to the head.phtml of your template.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the value after `Mage::run`.
The session is started after that call.
I don't know why you need to set something in the session before `Mage::run` but I have a feeling you can achieve what you need even if you set the value after `run`.
Use one of the events. Try it with `controller_action_predispatch`.  This event is dispatched before every page is loaded.
So if you need to change something in the content based on the session value, most probably you can observe that event.

Comment: I'm not master of Magento :)
If I set Myvar after "Mage::run" my not-changed-content is already here.

Comment: Here it is an example on how to create an observer: http://inchoo.net/category/magento/events-observers/

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Mage::` functions can only be done after the `Mage::run` call.

A workaround could be to use the PHP `setcookie()` method and use cookies to change your content.